# Converting xml string to Object class using jackson

Tags: java

Can someone please help in deserializing xml string : List<A> to Object.class using jackson in java.Xml looks like :

`<list> <A><id>1</id><name>Jeff</name> <id>2</id><name>John</name> </A>`

It returns a HashMap object if I convert it to Object.class . I have created a utility function XMLToObject which returns Object class. This will be typcasted on the caller function end to get the required type of Object.

```
public Object XMLtoObject(String xml){
    return mapper.readValue(xml,Object.class)
}
```

But if I use `List.class` in place of Object.class it deserializes it to list of hashmaps.

```
public Object XMLtoObject(String xml){
    return mapper.readValue(xml,List.class)
}
```

I am looking a way to convert it into Object.class which I can typecast  on caller function . Is that possible in jackson ? I know we can do it through xstream

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `List.class` is that it doesn't have any information about its elements. You need one of the overloaded `readValue` methods. For instance, using `TypeReference`:

```
return mapper.readValue(xml, new TypeReference<List<Object>>() {});
```

This creates an anonymous sub class of `TypeReference`, from which the complete generic type (`List<Object>`) can be read by Jackson. The result should therefore be a `List<Object>` instead of a `List<HashMap>`.

Comment: Thanks @Rob Spoor , my end goal is to convert xml into to an Object class object and then typecast this Object returned on the caller function end to either HashMap/List/Set  or any other collection.